Boundedness of linear interpolation formula
Consider the following implementation of linear interpolation:
lerp(x1, x2, y1, y2, x) = y1 * (x - x2) / (x1 - x2) + y2 * (x - x1) / (x2 - x1)

Is it true that x1 <= x <= x2 implies y1 <= lerp(x1, x2, y1, y2, x) <= y2 assuming IEEE 754 floating-point arithmetic, x1 < x2 and y1 < y2? If not, can you provide a counterexample?

Edit: Several answers present counterexamples where y1 and y2 are very close together. Is it possible to prove the bound assuming some lower bound on y2 - y1?

Some obvious counter examples: x1=x=x2 always results in NaN. For y1>y2 your inequality can't possibly hold. For y1=y2 every rounding error that does not cancel with another will break your inequality. And I doubt that you find a branch-less formula for lerp which fulfills that for all inputs.

Related.

Simply trying random numbers, with the desired ordering imposed, produces counterexamples, about one in ten million cases (from uniformly distributed 31-bit integers) for binary32.

I added another counter-example where y changes significantly, and same for x. You can try with arbitrary differences using the technique and iterate if you like to find other counter-examples.

No. Using IEEE-754 binary32,
x1 = 1.00000216,
x = 1.00000416,
x2 = 1.00002816,
y1 = 1.00000816, and
y2 = 1.00000A16 produces a linear interpolation result of 1.00000616, which is less than y1.

An additional counter-example:
Falsifiable. Counter-example:
  lerp = 2.0944565e-38 :: Float
  x1   = -3.8146973e-6 :: Float
  x2   =  4.6627863e34 :: Float
  y1   = 2.0944566e-38 :: Float
  y2   = 4.4969256e-23 :: Float
  x    = -6.327016e-34 :: Float

I generated this using the z3 SMT solver, scripted from Haskell bindings SBV, which allows you to reason about floating-point numbers (along with many other data types). (Source code)
The OP is wondering if there are counter examples when |y2-y1| has some lower bound. Here's a counter-example where Both y's and x's differ by at least 10:
Falsifiable. Counter-example:
  lerp =          -0.0 :: Float
  x1   = -3.3737146e38 :: Float
  x2   =  2.9109064e36 :: Float
  y1   =     -14.78452 :: Float
  y2   =  -6.905444e-2 :: Float
  x    =           0.0 :: Float

So, the answer is still no, at least not when x and y are at least 10 apart. (In fact, in this case y's are about 15 apart, and x's are widely separated.)
And here's another counter-example that avoids infinities altogether while keeping x's and y's quite separate from each other.
Falsifiable. Counter-example:
  lerp =  -1.924282e25 :: Float
  x1   =  -6.529187e10 :: Float
  x2   = 1.06079486e12 :: Float
  y1   = -1.9242819e25 :: Float
  y2   = -1.9242818e25 :: Float
  x    =  -3.871674e10 :: Float


x1 - x2 evaluates to Inf in single precision / 32 bit floating-point arithmetic. So admittedly a counterexample, but it still has a bit of an edge-case flavour...

@gTcV Added another counter-example that avoids all infinities. The advantage of this methodology is you can quickly iterate by imposing more and more constraints. Let me know if you want to try something else!

Code for the latest version: https://pastebin.com/LRbxUX6a

The absolute difference between y1 and y2 should not matter much. If you scale both y values by a power of two, the result scales by the same factor (assuming no overflow/underflow happens).

Candidate improvement:
Rather than
lerp(x1, x2, y1, y2, x) = 
y1 * (x - x2) / (x1 - x2) + y2 * (x - x1) / (x2 - x1)

Use the mathematically equivalent, yet numerically more stable:
(y1 * (x - x2) - y2 * (x - x1)) / (x1 - x2)


Good point. It's also faster (one division instead of two).

This won't be safe either. E.g., if you find A and B such that (A*B)/B > A, set x=x2, x2-x1=B, y2=A.

@chtz This form lessens the occurrence rate and degree to the problem.  It also offers an intro into other forms that reduce the rate.

If you have FMA, you can also do the obvious fusing of the multiplication and subtraction; which might yield better results.
